# How to use components as a template that all other components get rendered under that component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

How do I render every component under `<Container/>` and `<StyleProvider/>` component? I want to use the 2 components as a template. I am using `react-native-router-flux` for routing.

When `Actions.myAction()` is called, it calls the component required but it is not rendering under `<StyleProvider/>`

```
render(){
return (
    <Root>
        <StyleProvider style={getTheme(commonColor)}>  
            <Container>
                 <StatusBar backgroundColor="#386890" barStyle="light-content"/>
                 <Routes /> 
            </Container>
        </StyleProvider>
    </Root>)}
```

Here are my Routes

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux'
import Home from '../Home'
import Scan from '../Scan'
import Login from '../Login'
import ViewHistory from '../ViewHistory'
import History from '../History'
import Welcome from '../welcomeLoader/Welcome'
import Main from '../../../Main'


const Routes = () => (
   <Router>
     <Scene clone key = "root">
     <Scene key = "welcome" component = {Welcome} hideNavBar={true} initial = {true} />
     <Scene key = "history" component = {History}  hideNavBar={true} />
     <Scene key = "login" component = {Login} hideNavBar={true} />
     <Scene key = "scan" component = {Scan}  hideNavBar={true} />
     <Scene key = "viewHistory" component = {ViewHistory} hideNavBar={true} />
  </Scene></Router>)
export default Routes
```

Answer (score 0):

One brute force way of rerendering is to change the `key` on the component.

Thus in this case:

```
render(){
   return (
      <Root>
         <StyleProvider style={getTheme(commonColor)} key={commonColor}>  
            <Container>
                <StatusBar backgroundColor="#386890" barStyle="light-content"/>
                <Routes /> 
            </Container>
         </StyleProvider>
     </Root>
)}
```

Maybe add `key={commonColor}` as your component `key`, if that changes, it should rerender the tree.